# Why is the Alternative symbol of the ECMAScript RegExp grammar left recursive?

Tags: javascript, regex, grammar, ecma262

I cannot for the life of me figure out why Alternative is left recursive. It really throws a wrench into my parser.

```
Alternative :: 
    [empty] 
    Alternative Term
```

Here is a note in the semantics portion of the spec that is not exactly clear. Maybe the reasoning would be revealed once I understand this?

> NOTE Consecutive Terms try to
>   simultaneously match consecutive
>   portions of the input String. If the
>   left Alternative,  the right Term, and
>   the sequel of the regular expression
>   all have choice points, all choices in
>   the sequel are tried before  moving on
>   to the next choice in the right Term,
>   and all choices in the right Term are
>   tried before moving on to the next 
>   choice in the left Alternative.

What kind of parser can properly handle a left recursive grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for certain types of parser left-recursion is much better (e.g. for yacc - see section 6.2 [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-6.html) for an explanation).

If it's causing trouble for your particular parser, then by all means swap it over - it doesn't affect the definition of the language in any way.

Comment: I believe that my parser is known as a recursive descent parser and I am wondering what type of parser would be used without swapping the symbols. *PS: In case you haven't noticed I am new to this.*

Comment: The parser I mentioned in my answer, yacc, is an LALR(1) parser (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser).

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as I had previously switched the symbols around and ran in to no issues. I just wasn't sure if it could lead to unintended consequences in my final implementation.